# PayPal Integration Issue with Forbidden Error

Tags: javascript, paypal

I have an issue with PayPal payment integration. I want the payment to be integrated and I followed the instructions from: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/regional/mx/payment-selection-page/

My problem is that when I click on the payment button, I encounter a Forbidden error.

[image: [Image]]

I don't see any errors in the console either. Please guide me on this matter.

[image]

My code:

```
<div id="ppplus">
</div>
<button type="submit" id="miniBrowserInitiateCheckout"
        class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"
        onclick="initiateCheckout(); return false;">
    Checkout
</button>

<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/ppplusdcc/ppplusdcc.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
    function initiateCheckout() {
        var ppp = PAYPAL.apps.PPP({
            "approvalUrl": "approvalUrl",
            "placeholder": "ppplus",
            "payerEmail": "test@example.com",
            "payerFirstName": "First Name",
            "payerLastName": "Last Name",
            "payerTaxId": "",
            "miniBrowser": true,
            "mode": "sandbox",
        });
        console.log(ppp);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

PayPal Plus for MX is deprecated. Do not attempt to integrate it.

See the [standard](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) or [advanced](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/advanced/) guides instead.